# How do you get an output like this in Latex?

Tags: math-mode

[image]

[image]

How do you get an output like this in Latex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try `$\Lambda=\{\lambda_k\}_{k=-\infty}^\infty$`.

Comment: @marmot Do you want to write an answer?